# running scripts through processbuilder

Tags: java, scripting, processbuilder

I'm trying to run Python, Ruby, C, C++, and Java scripts from a java program, and Processbuilder was suggested to me as a good way to run the scripts. From what I understand, Processbuilder mostly runs native files (.exe on windows, etc.). However, I have heard a few things about running scripts (nonnative) files using Processbuilder. Unfortunately, everything I find on the subject is incredibly vague.

If someone could clarify a way to run nonnative scripts such as Python, Ruby, etc. I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the [`ProcessBuilder` documentation over at Sunoracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), but basically, you can run the interpreter for the scripting language and pass the script you want to run to it.

For example, let's say you have a script in `/home/myuser/py_script.py`, and `python` is in `/usr/bin/`

```
class ProcessRunner
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python", "/home/myuser/py_script.py");
        Process p = pb.start();
    }
}
```

An extremely basic example, you can get fancier with changing the working directory and change the environment.

You can also construct `ProcessBuilder` with a `String` array or a subtype of `List<String>`. The first item in the list should be the program/executable you want to run, and all the following items are arguments to the program.

```
String pbCommand[] = { "/usr/bin/python", "/home/myuser/py_script.py" };
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pbCommand);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to manually enter the entire location of the script, which may also result in portability issues, here's what I did:

```
String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python", pwd+'/'+scriptName, arg1, arg2);
Process p = pb.start();
```